# Remove data of a namespace from a Multi NameSpace XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have an XML as below. This XML has elements from 3 namespaces. I want to remove data and elements/attributes of 1 namespace and keep the final XML with 2 namepsaces and its elements.

**Development Environment:**
 1. Spring
 2. Java 8

```
<ns1:animals xmlns:ns1="http://.../animal" xmlns:ns2="http://.../tiger" xmlns:ns3="http://.../fish">
        <ns1:animalDescription>
            <ns1:animalType>fish</ns1:animalType>
            <ns1:animalLength>VALUE</ns1:animalLength>
            <ns1:partsOfBody>
               <ns1:eyes ns3:isCompund="true">
                  <ns1:countOfEyes>100</ns1:countOfEyes>
               </ns1:eyes>
               <ns3:gills>bigGills</ns3:gills>
         </ns1:animalDescription>
            <ns1:animalDescription>
            <ns1:animalType>TIGER</ns1:animalType>
            <ns1:animalLength>3 meter</ns1:animalLength>
            <ns1:partsOfBody>
               <ns1:eyes>
                  <ns1:countOfEyes>2</ns1:countOfEyes>
               </ns1:eyes>
               <ns2:tailLength>1 Meter</ns2:tailLength>
         </ns1:animalDescription>
    <ns1:animals>
```

I want to remove nameSpace xmlns:ns3="http://.../fish". I want the final XML as follows. I have tried doing string operations but its not usefule for complex xsd. I want to perform this using any XML API. Please guide me through this. What to use to acheive this. I am looking for an efficient solution.

```
<ns1:animals xmlns:ns1="http://.../animal" xmlns:ns2="http://.../tiger" xmlns:ns3="http://.../fish">
        <ns1:animalDescription>
            <ns1:animalType>fish</ns1:animalType>
            <ns1:animalLength>VALUE</ns1:animalLength>
            <ns1:partsOfBody>
               <ns1:eyes>
                  <ns1:countOfEyes>100</ns1:countOfEyes>
               </ns1:eyes>

         </ns1:animalDescription>
         <ns1:animalDescription>
            <ns1:animalType>TIGER</ns1:animalType>
            <ns1:animalLength>3 meter</ns1:animalLength>
            <ns1:partsOfBody>
               <ns1:eyes>
                  <ns1:countOfEyes>2</ns1:countOfEyes>
               </ns1:eyes>
               <ns2:tailLength>1 Meter</ns2:tailLength>
         </ns1:animalDescription>
    <ns1:animals>
```

FInal XML does not have following data.
1. ns3:isCompund="true"
2. bigGills

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="ns3:* ! @ns3:*" xmlns:ns3="http://.../fish"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

If you only have XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, replace the `xsl:mode` declaration with the standard shallow-copy identity template rule.